# Indentation in markdown files in neovim (nvchad)

Tags: lua, markdown, indentation, neovim

why am i not getting 8 indent spaces in neovim when it comes to markdown files. is there some standard, or something else. in visualstudio code, it is working fine.

in case of python, rust , i read that the community enforces it. but what is wrong with markdown files

i just added nvchad config using the command given on the official website. and in the init.lua inside `nvim/lua/core`, i changed the indent to 8 both `tabstop` and `shiftwidth`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, with NvChad, your configuration sets `shiftwidth` and `tabstop` to 2 => see https://github.com/NvChad/NvChad/blob/v2.0/lua/core/init.lua

You can add a specific configuration file in `lua/custom/init.lua` (see https://nvchad.com/docs/config/walkthrough).

In it, you could define a specific autocommand to set options for Markdown files :

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("FileType", {
  pattern = "markdown",
  callback = function()
    vim.opt.shiftwidth = 8
    vim.opt.tabstop = 8
    vim.opt.softtabstop = 8
  end,
})
```

Comment: got it. made my own config from scratch. :)

Comment: There is a duplicated open-parenthesis which will raise an error.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed my Lua code => remove duplicated open-parenthesis.